BMS 3S (S-8254A) with SJT-150E charger won't fully charge
Lately, i've been trying to use a BMS 3S that is based on the S-8254A IC to charge a group of three cells that I planned on using in series.

To charge the cells , I'm using a 12,6V 10A SJT-150E. This charger has a light on it that turns red when it's charging and green when it finished charging the batteries. The problem is, when I plug it in the input of the BMS, if the cell voltages are very low on charge (2,8 V, for example), the charger's light will turn red and the battery will start charging. After a while, the charger will start blinking red and green and, not long after that, it will turn green and stop charging the battery.

Yesterday, I've connected cells to the circuit at 3 V each. They've charged up to 3,7 V, but won't go past that. The charger keeps showing the green light and, when I disconnect the charger, the voltage on the output shows 0 V. At first, I thought that maybe some protection from the BMS could have acted, but the voltage on all cells are below the overcharge threshold from the IC datasheet. I would like to know if anyone has done something similar and if maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thank you all in advance!
Edit:
Adding the schematic of the BMS

{Source: ABLIC s-8254a datasheet (pdf), figure 11; web-page}

The charger probably exceeds the current limit of the BMS and makes it shut down (so it's just doing its job). What are the current limit of the BMS and that of the charger?

That makes sense. I didn't really think it could be the overcurrent being triggered because in the S-8254A datasheet, it's stated that, if the overcurrent protection is active, it stays that way until the load is unplugged or the charger is plugged. Maybe it activates again when I plug the charger, but it charged a little before. The datasheet states that the voltage on a pin (Vini) should be 0.13V for the protection to activate. Before that pin, there is a shunt resistor of 1 ohm, which apparently results in only 13 mA of current limit. I'll add the schematic to the original question.

Hi, Sam! Sorry for that, I guess I ended up missing that part on the rules. Thanks for the help on that, @DavideAndrea. The 4 mosfets on the PCB are the same ones from the schematic, but they are doubled on the PCB (each one from the schematic has another one in parallel with it). I've checked the PCB with the multimeter and the rest is the same as the schematic

@Lusca - Thanks for replying, I've deleted the earlier comments which are now obsolete.
